# PHP strtotime is off by 1 minute. NOT date string related

Tags: php, date, ms-access, time

Hi guys I have an access database, php query using ODBC_Exec.

I've got a While loop returning records from a an access database table into an HTML table on the page, where one of the fields contains a time. I am using StrToTime to format the date from access number into a readable date on the webpage. I am familiar that m is month and i is minute, I'm using i. There are other similar questions to mine where the person used "m" instead of "i" for minute and that through off their count by 1, this is NOT the same issue and not a duplicate question.

For the first two records returned by the loop, when they show up in the table they are correct. Every record after the first two results from the same loop comes out 1 minute behind for all subsequent times after the second.

Results are showing up as:

```
10/17/2016 03:35:00 PM
10/17/2016 03:39:00 PM
10/17/2016 03:44:00 PM
10/17/2016 03:49:00 PM
10/17/2016 03:54:00 PM
10/17/2016 03:59:00 PM
```

here is the code

```
$ApptQuery = "SELECT TBL_Appointments.*, TBL_Schools.*, TBL_Appointments_Status.*, TBL_Subjects.*
            FROM TBL_Schools INNER JOIN (TBL_Appointments_Status INNER JOIN (TBL_Subjects INNER JOIN TBL_Appointments ON TBL_Subjects.Subject_ID = TBL_Appointments.Appointment_Subject) ON TBL_Appointments_Status.Status_ID = TBL_Appointments.Appointment_Status) ON TBL_Schools.School_ID = TBL_Subjects.Subject_SchoolID
            WHERE TBL_Appointments.Appointment_Event=" . $Event_ID . "
            ORDER BY TBL_Appointments.Appointment_Time;";

            $ApptSQL = odbc_exec($Database, $ApptQuery);
            $ApptSQL2 = odbc_exec($Database, $ApptQuery);
            $Count = 0;
            Echo "<table class=\"DataTable\" border=\"1\"><tr><td>ID</td><td>Appointment Date</td><td>Time</td><td>Duration</td><td>Status</td><td>Subject ID</td><td>Subject Name</td><td>Action</td></tr>";
            While($Appointment = odbc_fetch_array($ApptSQL2))
            {
                $Appointment_ID = $Appointment['Appointment_ID'];
                $Appointment_Date = $Appointment['Appointment_Time'];
                $Appointment_Time = $Appointment['Appointment_Time'];
                $Appointment_Duration = $Appointment['Appointment_Duration'];
                $Appointment_Status = $Appointment['Appointment_Status'];
                $Appointment_StatusText = $Appointment['Status_DisplayText'];
                $Subject_StudentID = $Appointment['Subject_StudentID'];
                $Subject_NameFull = "" . $Appointment['Subject_NameFirst'] . " " . $Appointment['Subject_NameFirst'];
                $BookCode = "[<a href=\"?Page=AppointmentDetail&A=" . $Appointment_ID . "\">View</a>] [<a href=\"?Page=AppointmentDetail&A=" . $Appointment_ID . "\">Book</a>] [<a href=\"?Page=AppointmentDetail&A=" . $Appointment_ID . "\">Unbook</a>] [<a href=\"?Page=AppointmentDetail&A=" . $Appointment_ID . "\">Reserve</a>] [<a href=\"?Page=AppointmentDetail&A=" . $Appointment_ID . "\">Cancel</a>] [<a href=\"?Page=AppointmentDetail&A=" . $Appointment_ID . "\">Delete</a>]";
                Echo "<tr><td>" . $Appointment_ID . "</td><td>" . Date("m/d/Y", StrToTime($Appointment_Date)) . "</td><td>" . Date("h:i A", StrToTime($Appointment_Time)) . "</td><td>" . $Appointment_Duration . " min</td><td>" . $Appointment_StatusText . "</td><td>" . $Subject_StudentID . "</td><td>" . $Subject_NameFull . "</td><td>" . $BookCode . "</td></tr>";
            }
            Echo "<tr><td colspan=\"8\">" . $CountString . "</td></tr></table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't help debug your code but would respectfully suggest it might be easier to read (and then easier for someone else to debug, perhaps) if you used some 'staging' variables e.g. pesudocode:

```
$Appointment_Time_Text = StrToTime($Appointment_Date);
$Appointment_Date_Text = Date("m/d/Y", $Appointment_Time_Text);
```

One suggestion is that you could format the date/time as text in the SQL e.g. something like:

```
SELECT FORMAT( Appointment_Time,
          'mm/dd/yyyy hh:nn:ss AMPM' ) AS Appointment_Date_Text
  FROM TBL_Appointments
```